# What is the exact summation order of double, triple or n infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

When we write $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{i,j,k} $ for example, in what order do we mean by that? What are the partial sums here? Same for $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_{i,j,k}$, what exactly is our sequence?

Comment: The triple sum is a sum of sums of sums (like $\left(a+b+c+\cdots\right) + \left(a'+b'+c'+\cdots\right) + \left(a''+b''+c''+\cdots\right) + \cdots$, except with one extra layer of nesting); it's not one huge sum. It is computed by first computing the inner sums, then summing them up. Likewise for limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, you sum over $k$ first, producing an answer $b_{i,j}$ for each pair $(i,j)$. Then you sum over $j$, then over $i$.

The limit is interpreted the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I then fix a bijection $ f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{3} $ and prove that this summation order converges for $ a_{i,j,k} $, under which conditions (roughly, you can point me some keywords) does this sum correspond to the definition above? Also for limit?

Comment: @SeifeUndSalz If the series is absolutely convergent (i.e. the sum of the absolute values converges) then any rearrangement converges to the same sum and any such bijection will work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence

Comment: I think absolute convergence of the sum of sequence $ b_{n}=a_{f(n)} $ only guarantees that all bijection f converges to the same sum in this case, but still does not establish that this sum will also equal to the iterated sum above.

Comment: I think absolute convergence will imply that the iterated sum converges too. It's hard for me to imagine a counterexample with all terms positive. But I  haven't worked through this kind of proof since I was a graduate student very many years ago,