# What is the relationship between triple infinite series and summation of the same sequence in some order?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $ a_{i,j,k} $ be a sequence of real numbers. Fix a bijection  $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{3} $. Define the sequence $b_{n}$ as $ b_{n}=a_{f(n)} $. Then if the series $\sum b_{n}$ converges, and the iterated sum of $\sum_{i}^{\infty} \sum_{j}^{\infty} \sum_{k}^{\infty} a_{i,j,k} $ converges.

What is the relationship between the two? (the same question for a sequence over any number of indices)

Comment: I conjecture that the sums converging absolutely is equivalent to their equality for all bijections. I think too that if either sum converges absolutely they both do. See my comment at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228350/what-is-the-exact-summation-order-of-double-triple-or-n-infinite-series

Comment: I would like a proof but as I'm rereading the book Analysis of Terence Tao, it seems that what I'm looking for is the Fubini's theorem. If b_n is absolutely convergent, then summation over countable set can be defined as the infinite sum of b_n ( it is well defined regardless of the choice of the bijection f). Then Fubini claims that summation of the series of $a_{i,j,k}$ will be equal to summation over the set N^3 ( if it is defined, or in other words b_n is absolutely convergent).

Answer (score 0):

Let $ g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{3} $ be another bijection that also makes the series convergent. Then consider the permutation on N defined as $ h(n)=g^{-1}(f(n))$. Then $\sum a_{g(n)}=\sum a_{g(h(n))}=\sum a_{g(g^{-1}(f(n)))}=\sum a_{f(n)}$ because of rearrangement theorem. So if the series is absolutely convergent under a particular sum order, then it the same regardless of the order of term.

The Fubini's theorem for infinite sum  shows that if the series is absolutely convergent under some order then its result is the same as with the iterated sum.